# Google App Engine skip_files to skip entire folder

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm editing the `app.yaml` file so that all files within a particular folder are not uploaded to GAE.

Following the instructions found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref), I've tried the following:

```
skip_files:
    - /tester/^(.*/)?\.^(.*/)?$

skip_files:
    - /tester/.*

skip_files:
    - /tester/^(.*/)?#.*#$
```

None of the above seems to work, as new files added to the folder `tester` keep being pushed to GAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your directory is nested inside the project:

```
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?.*/some_dir/.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this works:

```
skip_files:

    - ^tester/*.*
```

Based on the results I got, it seems that:

- the initial `/` should not be included.
- the caret (`^`) is needed to tell the system where the string to interpreted begins;
- to include any file, the notation `*.*` seems to work.

Any comment is welcome!